# SQL(SQLite) and backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite-net

A beginner in SQL/DB here - I'm designing a universal windows app where a DB might come in handy, so I'm reading on SQL/SQLite and I'm wondering - how does backwards compatibility (classes/tables wise) works? Suppose I add or remove a property from a class that I've been using as a base for a table - will I still be able to interact with the old - class data and cast it into the updated class? How does one go about monitoring the added/ removed properties while querying the db?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Scenario - if I've got a User with 2 properties - 'Id', 'Name'.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And I've built an application with a 'Users' Db and I'm using that for a while. Then, I would like to add another property to my User- class. Suppose it's 'Age'. Can I add this new property to my original 'User' class and still be able to access the original Users table with:

```
var user = DbConnection.Table<User>().Where(x => x.Id == tId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Obviously, one option would be to keep the original User and create another class UserEx which will have the original properties + Age. Then I grab all 'User's, port them to UserEx and save to a new table.

This does seem a bit cumbersome to do for each added/ removed property though

Comment: @Kickaha why do you think that?

Comment: @Oyiwai: could you [edit] your question to add a simple example where you have a table, change the table, and then what you want to be able to do? That might help clarify what you're asking about, both for yourself and for people who read your question. It also would reduce the scope of your question, to make it [less broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Kickaha According to http://superuser.com/help/on-topic, "programming and software development" is off-topic there. And http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask is a copy of the one here.

Comment: @Kickaha this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Originally I thought this would me more suited to "software architecture and design" so Programmers.SE.. but I see your point about broad scope being universally unwelcome, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add this new property to my original 'User' class and still be
>   able to access the original Users table with ?

```
var user = DbConnection.Table<User>().Where(x => x.Id == tId).FirstOrDefault();
```

> Does adding a property to the user class update the underlying SQLLite
>   table? You would need to extend the class to maintain compatibility.

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set;}

        public User getUser(int tId)
        {
            var user = DbConnection.Table<User>().Where(x => x.Id == tId).FirstOrDefault();
            Id = user.Id;
            Name = user.Name;
            //age = user.age; // not possible
        }        
    }

    public class DetailedUser:User
    {
        public int age { get; set; }   

        public DetailedUser getUser(int tId)
        {
            var user = DbConnection.Table<User>().Where(x => x.Id == tId).FirstOrDefault();
            base.Id = user.Id;
            base.Name = user.Name;
            //age = user.age; // not possible
        }

        public DetailedUser getDetailedUser(int tId)
        {
            var user = DbConnection.Table<DetailedUser>().Where(x => x.Id == tId).FirstOrDefault();
            base.Id = user.Id;
            base.Name = user.Name;
            age = user.age;
        }
    }
```

The obvious 'cumbersome' process you outlined is another valid option. Either way when you are changing the data layer in your application there are consequences.

Two things come to mind, one is that in Android SqlLite has a onUpgrade function whey you can put your "cumbersome" data layer upgrade logic.. or you could use a NoSQL solution like MongoDB where the data layer is much more forgiving about the structure of your underlying records (ymmv).

Finally the better you plan your data layer structure the fewer times you will run into this kind of issue.

I hope that is of some help.